# Authentication with Amazon Cognito User Pools in Xamarin.Forms Cross-Platform App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am developing a cross-platform mobile application using Xamarin.Forms. I have an Amazon Cognito User Pool, equipped to do identity federation via third parties (Facebook, Google), as well as native application user auth (username/password), that contains all of my users. I currently have a single Cognito app client with a single redirect URL, `https://localhost:PORT`

I have written .NET Standard helper library that interfaces with Cognito. I have an interface `ICognitoAuthHelper` which contains a method `AuthenticateUserAsync(PoolRequest request)`. The `PoolRequest` object has an `AuthorizationCode` property which is used in auth code grant flows. The `AuthenticateUserAsync` function essentially posts the authorization code to the Cognito app client TOKEN endpoint to receive a JWT, which I then have the utility library decode to retrieve the claims about the authenticated user's identity.

Enter the problem: **I would like to leverage this utility library I have written to do authentication in my Xamarin.Forms app.**

Here's a simple use-case, and how I would (and do) execute an auth flow in an ASP.NET Core MVC web app:

**1)** I make the click of the "Login with Facebook" button redirect to the AUTHORIZE endpoint of the Cognito app client

**2)** When the app client redirects back to my redirect URL (`localhost`), I grab the `code` query parameter out of the URL, wrap it up in a `PoolRequest`, and feed it to my utility library. The library will then, as explained above, post the authorization code (`code`) to the TOKEN endpoint to begin the decoding process of the returned JWT.

**3)** The response from the utility library will contain the user claims, and I can redirect to a profile page, set session variables, etc.

**How can I achieve this sort of auth flow via a Xamarin.Forms app?** I have considered using a `WebView`, but am unsure as to how I can capture the auth code that will come back from the Cognito app client. What do I set as a redirect URL on the app client for Xamarin? How do I make the `WebView` navigate to a profile page after I decode the token set?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* have solved this issue. I do not own a Mac, so I have only been able to test on Android, but the solution entailed a couple of things:

- Registering a new redirect URL in the Cognito app client with a custom URL scheme. As an exmaple: `myapp://login`
- Creating two commands in the view model that is bound to my login view.

```cs
public ICommand FacebookLogin => new Command(FacebookLoginCommand);
public ICommand GoogleLogin => new Command(GoogleLoginCommand);

private async void FacebookLoginCommand()
{
    var redirect = "<COGNITO APP CLIENT AUTHORIZE URL (FB)>"; // 
    await Launcher.OpenAsync(redirect);
}

private async void GoogleLoginCommand()
{
    var redirect = "<COGNITO APP CLIENT AUTHORIZE URL (Google)>"; // 
    await Launcher.OpenAsync(redirect);
}
```

Note that here I am referencing the custom scheme redirect URLs, as described above, in the `redirect` varibale.

- Placing an `IntentFilter` on my `MainActivity` in the Android-specific project that specifies the custom URL scheme.

```cs
[IntentFilter(
    new [] { Intent.ActionView }, 
    DataScheme = "myapp", 
    DataHost = "login", 
    AutoVerify = true, 
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable})]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    ...
}
```

- Override the `OnNewIntent(Intent intent)` method in `MainActivity` to capture the authorization code query parameter. It can be extracted with `intent.Data?.GetQueryParameter("code")`.
- Use my utility library to exchange the code for tokens/user identity